# Laravel Code isn't applied to web page. How can I fix it?

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel framework for the first time. Writng the code and viewing on web page, it showed the code without applying. 
For example,

```
@if (Route::has('login'))
@auth HOME 
@else LOGIN 
@if (Route::has('register')) REGISTER 
@endif 
@endauth
@endif
```

How can I fix it?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Laravel
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Avobe code is the basic code of Laravel page. 
But the problem is the blade template isn't applied. 
@ or {} is showed just as it is. 
(Cause the length of the code is too long I deleted the part of style code.)

Comment: what is your view file extension?? `.blade.php` ??

Comment: Yes it is. 
app.blade.php

Comment: Can you put some screenshot??? So that we can help you

Comment: I attached it! Can you see that?

Comment: add the blade file of the page in the question.

Comment: don't think your view file is a blade file. make sure the file name

Comment: The file name is 'welcome.blade.php'.